# For xrdp, how t copy & paste back to windows host?

Tags: xrdp

I had xrdp installed my Ubuntu instance. It works great. Question are:

1. how do I copy & paste things back and forth between it and windows workstation just like a normal remote desktop between two windows computers ?
2. In /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini , set username works fine but setting password does not work. My password has symbols in it, like xyz#@! (is that the problem ?). If I set username and leave password to "ask," it works fine by entering the password on login. Setting both of them will be failed on login. How to make password setting work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**For the Copy/paste part,**

the easiest way would be to use the latest version of **Ubuntu (i.e. 16.10).**  This version contains the latest xrdp package version that includes the copy/paste feature.  You can have a look at the following links to obtain more information and to see how the drive redirection would work....

[Using Unity with XRDP](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10196)

[Using Mate Desktop with XRDP](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10165)

IF you have an older version, you could still use the copy/paste and drive redirection by compliling the xrdp packages.  You can try to follow [these instructions](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9285)

**For the password part,**

sound strange....Have you tried to copy/paste password from a text editor into the xrdp.ini file ? is it the same results ? is the keyboard layout set correctly,...

Hope this help

See ya